# What is the strange answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ragequit

I see some strange answers on this site: [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/10427/1045) and [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/10405/1045).

> Goodbye Lennart- Thank you Lennart - You win Lennart.Goodbye Lennart-

What does it mean?

**EDIT:** I did search and found a lot of these answers and question. Did somebody hacked this site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an ephemeral event that has been resolved.  

Comment: But I do like a refreshing dose of surrealism. Sounds like the name of edgy '90s rock album.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has been cleaned up now. If you see any other questions or answers like this, put a link here, and someone with edit rights can fix them.

Comment: yes, looks like it fixed

Comment: Yup. I just cleaned up the last of the flags, but it looked like our users took care of the rollbacks before I even noticed there was a problem. Pretty impressive self-correcting system we have here (and big thanks to Lennart and the other users who pitched in).